# How to verify if a variable value contains a character and ends with a number using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to check if a variable contains a character "C" and ends with a number, in minor version. I have :

```
my $str1 = "1.0.99.10C9";
my $str2 = "1.0.99.10C10";
my $str3 = "1.0.999.101C9";
my $str4 = "1.0.995.511";
my $str5 = "1.0.995.AC";
```

I would like to put a regex to print some message if the variable has C in 4th place and ends with number. so, for str1,str2,str3 -> it should print "matches". I am trying below regexes, but none of them working, can you help correcting it.

```
my $str1 = "1.0.99.10C9";

if ( $str1 =~ /\D+\d+$/ ) {
   print "Candy match1\n";
}
if ( $str1 =~ /\D+C\d+$/ ) {
   print "Candy match2\n";
}

if ($str1 =~ /\D+"C"+\d+$/) {
print "candy match3";
}

if ($str1 =~ /\D+[Cc]+\d+$/) {
print "candy match4";
}

if ($str1 =~ /\D+\\C\d+$/) {
print "candy match5";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($str1 =~ /C[^.]*\d$/)
```

- `C` matches the letter `C`.
- `[^.]*` matches any number of characters that aren't `.`. This ensures that the match won't go across multiple fields of the version number, it will only match the last field.
- `\d` matches a digit.
- `$` matches the end of the string. So the digit has to be at the end.

Comment: If the regex should not match `1.10.0.3CD8` (because the `D` is not part of a decimal number), then you need to refine the regex to `C\d+$`, I think.  And it might be that it should be as stringent as `[.]\d+C\d+$`.

Comment: The question just says "contains C and ends with a number". It doesn't say anything about not allowing other characters in addition to C.

Comment: Yes — it depends on what the "in minor version" clause means.  The question is under-specified to my way of thinking.

Comment: Although his attempted solutions don't seem to allow anything between the C and the number, so maybe that's an unstated requirement as well.

Comment: I took "in minor version" to mean everything after the last `.`.

Comment: `/[0-9]/` is generally better than `/\d/` because the latter will match Unicode characters like "৬".

Answer (score -1):

I found it really helpful to use https://www.regextester.com/109925 to test and analyse my regex strings.

Let me know if this regex works for you:

`((.*\.){3}(.*C\d{1}))`

Following your format, this regex assums 3 `.` with characters between, and then after the third `.` it checks if the rest of the string contains a C.

**EDIT:**

If you want to make sure the string ends in a digit, and don't want to use it to check longer strings *containing* the formula, use:

`^((.*\.){3}(.*C\d{1}))$`

Comment: That doesn't insist on a number (one or more digits) after the `C`.

Comment: This doesn't require the number to be at the end, since you have no `$` anchor.

Comment: @Barmar I assumed he meant that the character that follows has to be a digit.

Answer (score -1):

Lets look what regex should look like:

start{digit}`.`{digit}`.`{2-3 digits}`.`{2-3 digits}C{1-2 digits}end

- very very strict `qr/^1\.0\.9{2,3}\.101?C\d+\z/` - must start with `1.0.99[9]?.`
- very strict `qr/^1\.\0.\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}C\d{1,2}\z/` - must start with `1.0.`
- strict  `qr/^\d\.\d\.\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}C\d{1,2}\z/`
- relaxed `qr/^\d\.\d\.\d+\.\d+C\d+\z/`
- very relaxed `qr/\.\d+C\d+\z/`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @data = qw/1.0.99.10C9 1.0.99.10C10 1.0.999.101C9 1.0.995.511 1.0.995.AC/;
#my $re   = qr/^\d\.\d\.\d+\.\d+C\d+\z/;
my $re   = qr/^\d\.\d\.\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}C\d+\z/;

say '--- Input Data ---';
say for @data;

say '--- Matching -----';
for( @data ) {
    say 'match ' . $_ if /$re/;
}
```

Output

```
--- Input Data ---
1.0.99.10C9
1.0.99.10C10
1.0.999.101C9
1.0.995.511
1.0.995.AC
--- Matching -----
match 1.0.99.10C9
match 1.0.99.10C10
match 1.0.999.101C9
```

Comment: There's no need to constrain the beginning parts of the string. It's a distraction that's sure to break with real input.

Comment: Yes, it is intended to demonstrate how _strict_ we desire to constrain input data.